# Debugging android webview for hotspot sign-in page

Tags: android, webview, hotspot

I have a custom hotspot sign-in page for my wifi network.
The page doesn't load properly on the android webview that loads once I click on the network name (when it asks me to sign-in).
I think it is a JS error but I need a way to catch the error from that webview.

I have tested the page on Chrome, Firefox, Safari and webview test app.. it works fine with no issues.

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: Well, as a matter of fact, I don't remember the issue or how it was solved... but as for the question above, I know that I didn't find a way to debug the issue properly.